# DBPedia - Most relevant predicates per resource

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I'd like to determine the most relevant properties / predicates (not objects) for any resource in DBPedia and Yago (e.g. the top 20). For instance, intuitively for a music artist you would be interested in his age, genre, music label, records etc.

What should a good algorithm look like to solve this problem?
My current naive approach is the following.

First I retreive all classes, ordered by their "size". (Warning, very expensive query!)

```
SELECT distinct ?class (count(distinct ?e) as ?c)
WHERE {
    ?e rdf:type ?class .
}
ORDER BY DESC(?c)
```

Then I make a query for each of those classes to get the number of entities within that class that have that certain property.

```
SELECT distinct ?prop (count(distinct ?e) as ?c)
WHERE {
    ?e rdf:type <--CLASS--> .
    ?e ?prop []
}
ORDER BY DESC(?c)
```

`<--CLASS-->` is replaced by the URI of the respective class. After some post-processing this gives me a list like this:

```
"dbo:Agent": {
    "count": 1974654,
    "properties": {
        "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type": 399948,
        "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs": 67799,
        "dbp:name": 22272,
        "dbp:hasPhotoCollection": 13122,
        "http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/givenName": 10799,
        "dbo:birthPlace": 10055,
        "dbo:birthDate": 9953,
        "dbo:birthYear": 9735
    }
},
"dbo:Person": {
    count: 
...
```

It tells me, which properties are most relevant for which class. Of course "meta" properties like `http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs` should be ignored in a later step.

However, entities are in multiple classes and potentially every of those is important and gives additional information. E.g. `dbr:John_Lennon` is (among others) in `dbo:Person` and `dbo:MusicalArtist`. I need to combine these classes' property rankings. I thought of the following approach, but I'm unsure if this is actually a reasonable solution.

So my idea was to compute relative weights for every property (e.g. *propX* in *classA*) by dividing the number of entities within *classA* that have *propX* by the total number of properties in *classA*. If I want to merge two classes then, e.g. *classA* and *classB* (or *Person* and *MusicalArtist*), I'd simply rank the properties of both classes in combination, ordered by their relative weights (is this a legit comparison?). If a property occurs in both classes, I'd compute the harmonic mean over both for the ranking.

Assuming the above steps would actually make sense (please let me know what you think), I got one more problem. I want to combine information from DBPedia and Yago, so for `dbr:John_Lennon` I want to fetch the equivalent (`owl:sameAs`) `yr:John_Lennon` from Yago. How can I merge the property ranking from both datasets to finally get a list of top 20 most relevant properties consisting of a mix of both DBP and Yago properties?

Comment: It's not clear HOW you define relevancy. for instance, your example `dbr:John_Lennon` belong to `dbo:Person` and `dbo:MusicalArtist` because the latter is a subclass if the former. And obviously, some properties are more discriminative if they are only used by subclasses.

Comment: Defining "relevancy" in that case is actually not trivial. For example I also don't have an objective way of evaluating my solution once it's finished. The evaluation would probably be to manually look at some randomly picked examples and subjectively check, if the results are good or bad.
But do you still have any suggestions on how to proceed? Especially on the part of merging rankings among two or more datasets...